# Getting Synonyms from a Thesaurus

Tags: php, dictionary, artificial-intelligence, synonym

I'm looking for an API that detects POS (like a POS tagger) and returns synonyms to user.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's a real brain teaser there.

What if you pulled ALL the synonyms first, then for each synonym:

1. Recreate the phrase in question
2. Query google to see how many times that exact phrase has been used
3. Use the number of results you find to kick out the results that are nonsensical.

So, in your example, you'd pull all synonyms of field, and replace the word "field" with those synonyms.

When you got to "realm", google would give you ~400,000 results when you searched for "realm of computer science". That'd be a good hit, worth keeping.

When you got to "amphitheater", google would only give you 1 result when you searched for "amphitheater of computer science". That'd be a bad hit, remove "amphitheater" from the list of useable synonyms.

It'd take a bit of work, and wouldn't be useful in all contexts, but it might be a decent start.